# Attaching multiple db3 files using python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have 4 SQLite databases all with exactly the same schema but each has unique data.  I would like to combine all 4 and run queries against them.  I would also like to do some analysis with Pandas on various tables within the combined database.  This will be a repetitive taks that I would like to script.  I have some background in python and just trying to learn and utilize python in real world projects.

So far I have 4 .db3 files

```
db1
db2
db3
db4
```

All have identical schema just data from 4 sources.  I was trying to attach all 4 via python script using sqlite3 and running an `ATTACH` but having problems.

My idea is to iterate over the files in the folder and write to a new db, run custom queries, output to a dataframe, and conduct other sort/filter/match/graph operations.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("db1.db3")
conn2 = sqlite3.connect("db2.db3")
print("Opened db1 db successfully...")

c = conn.cursor()
c2 = conn2.cursor()

rows = c.execute("SELECT * from table_name")
c.execute("ATTACH db2.db3 as newdb")
print (rows)
print (type(rows))
dir(rows)
```

Looking for ideas guidance

Answer (score 0):

Consider a `UNION` query after `ATTACH` with an indicator for its source, all using one connection:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("db1.db3")    
print("Opened db1 db successfully...")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("ATTACH 'db2.db3' as db2")
c.execute("ATTACH 'db3.db3' as db3")
c.execute("ATTACH 'db4.db3' as db4")

union_sql = '''SELECT *, 'db1' as source
               FROM table_name 
               UNION ALL
               SELECT *, 'db2' as source
               FROM db2.table_name 
               UNION ALL
               SELECT *, 'db3' as source
               FROM db3.table_name 
               UNION ALL
               SELECT *, 'db4' as source
               FROM db4.table_name 
            '''

rows = c.execute(sql)

for r in rows.fetchall():
    print(r)
...
```

And for pandas, pass above union query into a [`read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html):

```
df = pd.read_sql(union_sql, conn)

df.shape
df.dtypes
df.describe(include='all')

df.head(10)
df.tail(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I will let you know if it works.